# DefaultHttpClient throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, rest, restful-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to consume a RESTful web service using Java, and have been following the tutorial on [4.8 Preemptive Authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/tutorial/html/authentication.html).

However, I keep getting an InvocationTargetException error, and started moving bits and pieces of the code out to track down the source.

I have my code down to essentially one functional line:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class TestRestClient() {

  public void doStuff() {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: [Result of getAllStackTrace() in a finally block](http://pastebin.com/P92fHvWm)

Comment: Could you post your stack trace as well?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting one.  It won't let me catch an InvocationTargetException from that method, as it doesn't think there will ever be one to catch.